# How to draw a plot symbol shadow behind the symbol fill in coreplot?

Tags: core-plot

Is it possible to draw a symbol shadow behind the symbol fill? As explained here, [CorePlot Issue 478](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=478) the fill is drawn after the plot fill which results in something that looks like this, [image: a coreplot symbol], where the red is the shadow and blue is the fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Plot issue #478 is fixed. Pull the latest code to fix the symbol drawing.

If you don't want to do that, the fix involves adding a transparency layer to the symbol drawing. See the [diff](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/detail?r=cb8b991b805a72e8c7499191d47d2c36285fe2fd) for the change to see how to fix your copy. The previous changeset fixes the `-copyWithZone:` issue mentioned on the issue tracker, too.

Comment: Great, thank you! I didn't expect it to get fixed so quickly!