# How to prevent overlapping shadows when points are close together in coreplot?

Tags: core-plot

After the recent fix regarding rendering, [How to draw a plot symbol shadow behind the symbol fill in coreplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542456/how-to-draw-a-plot-symbol-shadow-behind-the-symbol-fill-in-coreplot) the shadows are drawn behind the point.

However, core plot applies the shadows individually to each data point when using the delegate `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` which results in overlapping shadows when data points are close together. For example, [image: shadow overlap when points are close together core-plot]

Is it possible to avoid the shadow overlap of the perviously rendered data point? For example by rendering the shadows in a separate layer in a single sweep (or some other way)?

Comment: I think I will have a look at changing the rendering order: (1) line, (2) shadow, (3) stroke, for each point, then do another sweep and provide the fills. If anybody had guidance please let me know.